# How should I wire / connect a new ceiling light to this ceiling junction box?

Tags: wiring, ceiling, light

UPDATED CEILING JUNCTION BOX PHOTO PROVIDED.

I’m wondering if I can ask for some assistance in installing a new ceiling light to an unused (blank plate)ceiling junction box. The light switch in the room has 3 unused switches.

This is the light fixture which is pretty standard.
[image]

There is a black, white and copper wire.

When I removed the ceiling junction cap, this is where I am puzzled.

[image]

[image]

There are 6 wires capped.
2 separate whites with double wires.
1 black with double wire.
1 red double wire.
1 orange single wire
1 green multiple wires.

The orange wire is from the side hole.
The red wire comes from the bottom 2 holes.
1 white comes from bottom right and middle hole.
1 white comes from bottom right and top left hole.
The black comes from bottom right and top left hole.
The green comes from side hole and bottom left hole.

I guess all these wires are due to the 3 switches in the room?

I first wired the fixture copper wire to the green ground screw on the mount not shown here.

Then wired the junction double black to fixture black, and 1 junction double white to the fixture white. The light turned on but won’t turn off from any of the 3 switches.  Changing to the 2nd double white to fixture white resulted in the same, with light on and unable to turn off.  So either whites to the fixture white is unable to allow the light to shut off.

How should I actually be wiring this so that the light turns on and off according to the switch.

I hope I explained the ceiling wires properly.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what country are you in?

Comment: Toronto, Canada

Comment: A better picture of the celing box showing which conduit each wire comes from would be helpful.

Comment: Will snap another photo in daylight when I can tomorrow!  Thank you!

Comment: Was there a light here previously, or was it just a blank plate?

Comment: Blank plate, so I couldn’t rely on past wiring to hook up the new one.

Comment: I’ve updated the photo with the ceiling junction box and conduit, hopefully these will help. Thank you for any guidance provided!

Comment: I'll be honest, this makes no sense to me.  The issue that I have isn't about which wires are switched hots, but rather why neutral wires are mis-colored (yellow?) or not included in the same conduits as the hots.  Either would be a code violation. Any chance you can give us some pictures of what is inside the box with the switches?  I just don't want you to "guess" and find that it "works", but it works in a way that is actually unsafe.

Comment: For sure, I’ll try to remove the switch to take a photo of the switch box.

Comment: @bigchief I am not sure what your issue is but there is nothing unsafe I can see. there are white neutrals and green grounds along with red black yellow and browns probably all hots / travelers or switched hots not unusual in my opinion and if the brown single is switched exactly how I might have wired it.

Comment: @Ed Beal I guess the only thing that concerns me is the two conduits shown without white neutrals. Do you think these are both switch loops, travelers for 3-way, or do you think they used a non-standard color for neutral?

Comment: @bigchief prior to the new requirement last code cycle to have a neutral in the switch box many multiple switch setups only had the neutral at the fixture with no neutrals run to the switches, just the travelers and hot. Now we need the neutral at at least 1 location per NEC 404.2.C, when conduit is used no neutral is required because it can be pulled later.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a non contact voltage tester? Or volt meter? I would test the single brown to see if it is switched.
This may work like the single brown and single white, taking white to the white  to the fixture  and the brown to black the bare copper goes to the green.

Would be my first shot at it the black tape on the brown would be the hot going down to the switch the way I wire in conduit the tape is to remind me where the hot is.  If you have a tester or meter I would check the brown to verify it is switched but if not make the connections with the breaker off and give it a try.

Comment: What about the single brown? Are there 2 switches for this fixture? With the power on toggle the switch   And check both positions for the brown single wire.

Comment: I was trying to add more to the previous comment. 

I used a contact voltage tester and here were the results. 

The black is the only hot wire, when master switch was off, normal. 

When master was on and testing with the 3 switches: 

With right side switch on, black and red wire were hot. 

With the left side switch on, black and red wire were hot. 

With middle switch on, Black, red and also the single brown/orange wire were hot.

Comment: I’m surprised the white wires from the junction box were not hot with any switch. 

Am I correct in saying I should try the brown single wire to the white from the light fixture?

Comment: I think you were right in deducing single brown to single white, that matched with what was found from voltage test.  I’ll try when there is daylight tomorrow.  Thank you so much for your answer above!

Comment: Running a switch loop on white is common when nmb or Romex is used but when using conduit you have the entire rainbow, in that case only green white and gray are not used for a hot, you might get away with it but it would not be normal.

Comment: Ok multiple switches that is what I had guessed but was not following the term master. Electricians use 3 way and 4 way in this case with 3 switches there will normally be 2ea 3 way switches and 1ea 4 way. If you ever change switches take photos of each switch because it is easy to get the wires mixed up if 2 wires the same color I even mark 1 prior to taking the photo. You will thank me. Even electricians have trouble getting them right that’s how I got my start figuring a 5 switch combo that the electrician goofed up, he was a good master electrician and quite a craftsman with conduit

Comment: Ed Beal you’re the boss! Just like you initially said, brown wire to white on fixture, black to black on fixture, and copper to green.   This worked and light fixture is up and running!  Thank you so much again!

Comment: If you accept the answer the green check mark that will help others find this answer when searching, that’s the proper way to provide thanks on this site. Glad it worked.